# Where can I download iOS 5 SDK?

Tags: ios, ios5, sdk

I am not able to find iOS 5 SDK on the apple app store. Where else can I download it from?

Comment: I saw that thread before. It turns out that you cannot download older versions of XCode either.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a serious development issue. I have not used iOS5 before, but I want my apps to be built for that platform, but apple doesn't seem to even allow me to do it.

Comment: This question should read: "How can I download old versions of Xcode?" The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047735/where-can-i-download-old-versions-of-xcode

Comment: This question should read: "How can I download old versions of Xcode?"

Comment: Use Xcode 4.5.x like everyone else. If you want your app to support iOS 5.x in addition to iOS 6 then all you need to do is set your project's Deployment Target to iOS 5.0 or 5.1 as desired.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to be able to support older versions of iOS, set the deployment target to the minimum OS you want the app to run on. You don't need an older SDK for that.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. The app works fine on iOS 5, but crashes on iOS6. It's the email bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567708/monotouch-ios-6-crash-when-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Ok, so if you're using a 3rd party dev framework you might need an older SDK for that. Fair enough.